# How to stop my jquery to listen to all rows of data?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown when the reject checkbox is ticked. I have done this simply with Jquery but however because I need the function on all of the data that is pulled in, it copies the classes to the next row and so on, so when i check the reject button it opens all the dropdown text areas to input a reason. I was wondering how i would go about making this for an unlimited amount of data????? so it only ever opens one dropdown textarea.

I have read online that I can do this with php parenting? As my PHP skills are weak to say the least is there any simpler ways of going about this?

HTML
          
            
              Name
              Username
              Email
              Verify
              Reject

```
        if ($supplier['Id'] != '3') { ?>
        <tr class="unverifiedSuppliers">
          <td width="150"><?php echo $supplier['Name']; ?></td>
          <td width="150"><?php echo $supplier['Username']; ?></td>
          <td width="250"><?php echo $supplier['Email']; ?></td>
          <td width="40"><input type='checkbox' name='verifySupplier[]' value='<?php echo $supplier['Id']; ?>' /></td>
          <td width="40"><input class="checked" type='checkbox' name='rejectSupplier[]' value='<?php echo $supplier['Id']; ?>' /></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
          <td colspan="5">
            <label>Reason:</label>
            <textarea name="rejectReason[<?php echo $supplier['Id']; ?>]"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } } ?>
      </table>


Jquery

$(function() {
$('.checked').change(function() {
    $('.dropdown').toggle();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$('.checked').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

`$(this)` is the DOM element you changed.

`.closest('tr')` is looking for the closest parent with the jQuery selector 'tr', wich mean the closest `<tr></tr>`.

`.next('.dropdown')` is looking for the immediate next sibling with the jQuery selector '.dropdown'.

**Side note** - using the selector here is facultative, it will just return an empty element if the next element doesnt have the class `dropdown`.

Comment: That has stopped the functionality completely. Any other ideas? Literally stumped on this one..

Comment: It is working fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/nFwAD/ Did you remove the `$(function(){...})`? if yes, then you shouldnt have.

Comment: you Karl are a legend!

Comment: Thank you so much, For the people that might need to do this do you mind explaining what the jquery is doing, as well for myself :D

Comment: @MaxwellLynn did, hope it help.